# how to make a valid JSON out of a string with non-quoted keys?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the followign python problem:

```
'{acorn: 15,acorn_type: 15,area_name: "London",beds_max: 1,beds_min: 1,branch_id: "21062",branch_name: "Realm Estates",brand_name: "Realm Estates",chain_free: false,company_id: "10832",country_code: "gb",county_area_name: "London",currency_code: "GBP",display_address: "Lancaster Mews, Wandsworth SW18",furnished_state: "unfurnished",group_id: "",has_epc: true,has_floorplan: false,incode: "1BA",is_retirement_home: false,is_shared_ownership: false,listing_condition: "pre-owned",listing_id: 45296714,listing_status: "to_rent",listings_category: "residential",location: "London",member_type: "agent",num_baths: 1,num_beds: 1,num_images: 5,num_recepts: 1,outcode: "SW18",post_town_name: "London",postal_area: "SW",price: 1300,price_actual: 1300,price_max: 1500,price_min: 1250,price_qualifier: "",property_highlight: "",property_type: "flat",region_name: "London",section: "to-rent",size_sq_feet: "",tenure: "",zindex: "686544"}'
```

I would like to `json.load()` this string, but clearly all the keys are wrong. it should be `'acorn: 15,...` and so on. How could I go bout replacing all words before a `:` into a string? thanks

Comment: This is valid YAML, you can parse it with `yaml.load()`.

Comment: I see! i had no idea about that. thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman But you shouldn't. because `yaml.load()`  is documented to be unsafe. There is no execuse for not using `yaml.safe_load()` in this case (and most others).

Comment: @FlorianOswald As formatted your "problem" looks like a string that starts with a single quote. If those quotes are not part of the input you should take them away. Even better: show a more complete example like an assignment `s = '{acorn: 15....}'` or `s = """'{acorn: 15....}'"""`, so it is unambiguous what your input is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @daniel-roseman comment, it is better to use yaml to load your string into dict:

```
import yaml,json
string='{acorn: 15,acorn_type: 15,area_name: "London",beds_max: 1,beds_min: 1,branch_id: "21062",branch_name: "Realm Estates",brand_name: "Realm Estates",chain_free: false,company_id: "10832",country_code: "gb",county_area_name: "London",currency_code: "GBP",display_address: "Lancaster Mews, Wandsworth SW18",furnished_state: "unfurnished",group_id: "",has_epc: true,has_floorplan: false,incode: "1BA",is_retirement_home: false,is_shared_ownership: false,listing_condition: "pre-owned",listing_id: 45296714,listing_status: "to_rent",listings_category: "residential",location: "London",member_type: "agent",num_baths: 1,num_beds: 1,num_images: 5,num_recepts: 1,outcode: "SW18",post_town_name: "London",postal_area: "SW",price: 1300,price_actual: 1300,price_max: 1500,price_min: 1250,price_qualifier: "",property_highlight: "",property_type: "flat",region_name: "London",section: "to-rent",size_sq_feet: "",tenure: "",zindex: "686544"}'
dict_version = yaml.safe_load(string)
print dict_version

#if you need json version
json_version = json.dumps(dict_version)
print json_version
```

which give you:

```
{'listing_status': 'to_rent', 'outcode': 'SW18', 'brand_name': 'Realm Estates', 'member_type': 'agent', 'chain_free': False, 'area_name': 'London', 'is_shared_ownership': False, 'country_code': 'gb', 'beds_max': 1, 'property_type': 'flat', 'incode': '1BA', 'furnished_state': 'unfurnished', 'branch_id': '21062', 'listing_id': 45296714, 'has_floorplan': False, 'beds_min': 1, 'section': 'to-rent', 'company_id': '10832', 'price_min': 1250, 'zindex': '686544', 'location': 'London', 'county_area_name': 'London', 'acorn_type': 15, 'is_retirement_home': False, 'price_max': 1500, 'listing_condition': 'pre-owned', 'display_address': 'Lancaster Mews, Wandsworth SW18', 'region_name': 'London', 'price': 1300, 'num_images': 5, 'listings_category': 'residential', 'branch_name': 'Realm Estates', 'post_town_name': 'London', 'acorn': 15, 'num_recepts': 1, 'size_sq_feet': '', 'price_qualifier': '', 'postal_area': 'SW', 'property_highlight': '', 'price_actual': 1300, 'num_baths': 1, 'num_beds': 1, 'has_epc': True, 'tenure': '', 'group_id': '', 'currency_code': 'GBP'}
{"listing_status": "to_rent", "outcode": "SW18", "brand_name": "Realm Estates", "member_type": "agent", "chain_free": false, "area_name": "London", "is_shared_ownership": false, "country_code": "gb", "beds_max": 1, "property_type": "flat", "incode": "1BA", "furnished_state": "unfurnished", "branch_id": "21062", "listing_id": 45296714, "has_floorplan": false, "beds_min": 1, "section": "to-rent", "company_id": "10832", "price_min": 1250, "zindex": "686544", "location": "London", "county_area_name": "London", "acorn_type": 15, "is_retirement_home": false, "price_max": 1500, "listing_condition": "pre-owned", "display_address": "Lancaster Mews, Wandsworth SW18", "region_name": "London", "price": 1300, "num_images": 5, "listings_category": "residential", "branch_name": "Realm Estates", "post_town_name": "London", "acorn": 15, "num_recepts": 1, "size_sq_feet": "", "price_qualifier": "", "postal_area": "SW", "property_highlight": "", "price_actual": 1300, "num_baths": 1, "num_beds": 1, "has_epc": true, "tenure": "", "group_id": "", "currency_code": "GBP"}
```

Comment: This output is not json.

Comment: @blhsing And ? What the OP wants is to be able to parse this to Python, so the answer solves the problem. And if the OP wants to jsonify it, once he has the python representation he just have to pass it to  `json.dumps()`, so this ALSO solves the "problem" of turning it into proper json if needed.

Comment: Add the json version to close the comment propagation :-)

Comment: Never, ever, use `yaml.load()`, when `yaml.safe_load()` can do the job. There is no excuse for recommending something that is documented (in the PyYAML docs itself) to be potentially unsafe.